# How to fix "E: Package 'libatlas-dev' has no installation candidate" While installing Scipy for Scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, ubuntu-18.04

how do i fix this problem i gave

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3-base
```

to install scipy for installing scikit learn and got an error like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libatlas-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libatlas-base-dev:i386 libatlas-base-dev

E: Package 'libatlas-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried updating but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try the solution mentioned on the following link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056167/how-to-install-atlas-on-kubuntu-18-04bionic

Answer (score 7):

I tried to install `libatals-dev` on my raspberry `pi` and my `pi` told me **this**:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done
>
> Package `libatlas-dev` is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> However the following packages replace it:
> `libatlas-base-dev`
>
> E: Package `libatlas-dev` has no installation candidate

So please try `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` instead.

Comment: Tried to install `libcblas-dev` but got the no installation candidate, the dependency that was missing was solved when installing `libatlas-base-dev` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have been misdirected by Google into following instructions on a page such as https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/install.html. If the goal is to install `scikit-learn` you may be better off with just `pip3 install -U scikit-learn` according to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html. That's what I did on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.